# Spring Boot Actuator: как включить кириллицу?

Tags: java, spring

В **pom.xml** подключаем:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

В **applilication.properties** пишем:

```
management.info.env.enabled=true
info.app.encoding = @project.build.sourceEncoding@
info.name = Приложение Spring Data Rest
info.description = Описание приложения
info.author = Автор приложения
```

Идём по адресу **localhost:8080/actuator/info** и видим:

```
{
"app": {
    "encoding": "UTF-8",
},
"name": "ÐÑÐ¸Ð»Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Spring Data Rest",
"description": "ÐÐ¿Ð¸ÑÐ°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ Ð¿ÑÐ¸Ð»Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ",
"author": "ÐÐ²ÑÐ¾Ñ Ð¿ÑÐ¸Ð»Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ"
}
```

Как так-то? UTF-8 и кракозябры. Как сделать хорошо? :)

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему переводом конфига с application.properties на application.yml. Так кодировка человечья :)

Answer (score 0):

Значит надо, чтобы кодировка самого файла и название кодировки, которое передаётся браузеру, совпадали. Надо проверить и там и там.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: вообще стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Файлы *.properties идут с первой Java и кодировка в них ISO-8859-1. Соответственно, юникод там прописать можно, но вот такими символами: \u00c0 и т.д. В общем, перевёл конфиг на YML, там с кодировкой всё в порядке.